# How do I display a large number in scientific notation?

Tags: numbers, autoit, numeric, integer-overflow

Using AutoIt, when I multiply `1` by `10^21`, I get `1e+021`. But in separate steps, such as multiplying `1` by `10^3` seven times, I get the overflow value of `3875820019684212736`.

It appears AutoIt cannot handle numbers with more than eighteen digits. Is there a way around this?  For example, can I multiply `10,000,000,000,000,000` by `1000` and have the result displayed as `1e+019`?

Comment: I would search for an autoit bignum library like [this one](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/83529-bignum-udf/). That one returns results in string form and without exponential notation so you may have to parse the output to get what you want.

Comment: Also worth noting: depending on what you are trying to do, autoit may not be the best language for you. For example: python can handle arbitrarily large integers without the need for any extra library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF : [BigNum UDF](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/83529-bignum-udf/)

Example :

```
$X = "9999999999999999999999999999999"
$Y = "9999999999999999999999999999999"
$product = _BigNum_Mul($X, $Y)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing such an excellent and detailed example.